# UIImageView not displaying

Tags: swift, uikit

This is the swift code:

```
if let myImagePth = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "testImage", ofType: "jpg", inDirectory: "myImages"
{
        let myUIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: myImagePath)
        var myUIImageView = UIImageView(image: myUIImage)
        myUIImageView.center = self.view.center
}
```

I verified that "myUIImageView" does have a position and that the image path is correct, but I am not sure why it is not displaying. This code is written in the viewcontroller. I am starting to think that it might not be linked to the viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You should add it ti view and set a frame

```
var myUIImageView = UIImageView(image: myUIImage)
view.addSubView(myUIImageView)
myUIImageView.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:100,height:100)
myUIImageView.center = self.view.center
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ImageView has not been added to the view. Below code will display the image in the center of view controller.

```
if let myImagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "testImage", ofType: "jpg", inDirectory: "myImages") {
        let myUIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: myImagePath)
        let myUIImageView = UIImageView(image: myUIImage)
        
        myUIImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(myUIImageView)
        myUIImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
        myUIImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: -50.0).isActive = true
    }
```